# iOS App download restriction as per screen size

Tags: iphone, ios7

I want my app only to be downloaded onto 4 inch screen iPhones.
 - Does AppStore have such restriction while I submit the app?

If at all a programmer can mention that restriction in code, please help me how to do that?

Comment: This would get you rejected from the App Store. You must support both sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't.
But you can restrict by issuing an alert with "Not Supported device"
using the device size with `[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size` during app initialisation.
Atleast we prompt to user stating, this device is not support!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it directly on XCode, but you can check the device type to know which device user is using: in case of normal iPhone you can show a courtesy message.

Here is the code I use in my application:

**DeviceCheck.h**

```
#define isIPad     ([DeviceCheck getDeviceType] == DeviceTypeIPad)
#define isIPhone   ([DeviceCheck getDeviceType] == DeviceTypeIPhone)
#define isIPhone5  ([DeviceCheck getDeviceType] == DeviceTypeIPhone5)

enum {
    DeviceTypeIPad,
    DeviceTypeIPhone,
    DeviceTypeIPhone5
}; typedef NSUInteger DeviceType;


@interface DeviceCheck : NSObject

    + (DeviceType)getDeviceType;

@end
```

**DeviceCheck.m**

```
#import "DeviceCheck.h"

static DeviceType _type = -1;


@implementation DeviceCheck

+ (DeviceType)getDeviceType {

    if(_type == -1) {
        _type = DeviceTypeIPad;
        CGFloat pixelHeight = CGRectGetHeight([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds);

        if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
            if (pixelHeight == 480.0f)      { _type = DeviceTypeIPhone; }
            else if (pixelHeight == 568.0f) { _type = DeviceTypeIPhone5; }
        }
    }

    return _type;
}

@end
```

Now in your application you can check the device with this simple cose:

```
if(isIPad)         { NSLog(@"I'm an iPad"); }
else if(isIPhone)  { NSLog(@"I'm an iPhone 4 / iPhone 4s"); }
else if(isIPhone5) { NSLog(@"I'm an iPhone 5 / iPhone 5c / iPhone 5s"); }
```